# I want to gradually move from Heroku to AWS. How to do setup "Weighted routing policy" in Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, devops, amazon-route53

This problem is hurting my brains for almost the whole weekend. I hope someone will come and release me :-)

I want to move a webapplication from Heroku to AWS in a gradual way. So, i.e. that we start routing 10% of the request to AWS, and increase that number in time – when our canary tests passed and everything runs smoothly. FYI; the database is already moved to AWS and can also be accessed by Heroku via a Network Load Balancer.

The setup should also be able to serve a maintenance-page (running from s3 bucket with cloudfront) when – in some hopefully rare case – the health checks for both are failing. I've added an extra alias record for that with a weight of 0, because route53 will always try to give a result when all checks are failing, even if the weight is set to nil.

The Application Load Balancer we need for routing all the traffic to the correct ECS containers, also arrange some redirects (apex to www, and http to https) for us.

With all these requirement, I came up with the diagram shown below.

[image: Like this]

During implementation, I run into a problem that I do not get solved.

I can't create an specific A-Record (the one with weight 100), because it tries to refer to an recordset as alias which is from another type (CNAME). And that's not allowed within Route 53.

The problem is that it has to be a A-record, because when you want to leverage the 'weighting routing policy', all dns record should be from the same type.

The records with weight 90 and 10 should also be CNAME's (the need to be from the same type as well), because I can't use a A-record for my Heroku endpoint.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this? Our maybe knows a better way to do this?

Comment: Make all the www records CNAMEs?

Comment: Thanks, that is also an option. But isn't it better to use aliases?

Comment: Yes, it's better when possible, but here, that isn't possible (or doesn't appear to be).